# Draw 2d map according to characters position

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've written this code to draw a map according to a characters position:

```
public void drawBoard(Tile[][] map, Graphics g){
            int horizontalDifference = windowWidth / 8; //Spacing between images
            int verticalDifference = windowHeight / 8;
            for(int i = bobby.x - 4; i<=bobby.x + 4; i++){
                for(int j = bobby.y - 4; j<=bobby.y + 4; j++){
                    if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i > map.length - 1 || j > map[0].length - 1){
                        continue; //Out of bounds, don't draw this tile
                    }
                    g.drawImage(imageManager.returnImage(map[i][j]), i*horizontalDifference, j*verticalDifference, rootPane);
                }
            }
        }
```

`map` is a array of my tiles containing information about the tile. `imageManager` can return an image to draw when given the tile variable. For some reason this isn't drawing correctly at all, the images aren't drawn in the correct order and it isn't drawing according to the users position (The map doesn't shift accordingly if I change the users x and y). Can anyone see a visible mistake in my method? I can try to provide a runnable example if it isn't obvious to somebody.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from how you are using variables i and j. the way you use them makes it so your

```
g.drawImage();
```

calls are drawing to places off screen. For example lets say:

```
windowWidth = 800;
windowHeight = 800;
bobby.x = 20;
bobby.y = 20;
```

your for loops will get the correct images based on your Tile[][] map, but they will draw in the wrong spot. For example the first iteration of your for loops will draw images at these locations:

```
(16 * 100, 16 * 100)
(16 * 100, 17 * 100)
(16 * 100, 18 * 100)
(16 * 100, 19 * 100)
```

which are all off screen. what you could so instead is say

```
for(int i = -4; i <= 4; i++){
    for(int j = -4; j <= 4; j++){
        if(bobby.x + i < 0 || bobby.x + i > map.length - 1 || bobby.y + j < 0 || bobby.y + j > map[0].length - 1) continue;
        g.drawImage(imageManager.returnImage(map[bobby.x+i][bobby.y+j],(i+4)*horizontalDifference,(j+4)*verticalDifference,rootPane);
    }
}
```

if you have any further questions feel free to ask, otherwise mark the problem as resolved. hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, that makes sense! Im getting out of bounds exceptions now though because if [bobby.x+i] or [bobby.y+j] is less than 0 or larger than the map length/width, it attempts to access a map tile that doesn't exist.  I attempted `if(bobby.x + i < 0 || bobby.x + i > map.length - 1 || bobby.y + j < 0 || bobby.y + j > map[0].length - 1) continue;` but it still draws incorrectly :/ Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give me an example of when this happens? include for me, bobby.x, bobby.y map.length, map[0].length, i,j.

Comment: This is my map http://pastebin.com/uCVdEaz5 , bobby.x is set to 1, bobby.y is set to 1. It should draw the top and left wall exactly 1 space above and left of the center, though it draws a 5x5 square of 1s with the topleft-most one located in the top left corner

Comment: My mistake, i made a slight error in the last chunk of code in my original solution. I was drawing at i * horizontalDisplay, which would be negative half the time and not be seen, when i should have been drawing at (i + 4) * horizontalDisplay. The same goes for the vertical Display. Please update the chunk you copied from me with the revised chunk.